# Evaluation of the integral $\int 3x \cos x^2 \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I want to solve this:

$$\int 3x \cos x^2 \, dx$$

I get this answer:

$$
\frac{\sin 2x}{2}+\frac{\cos 2x}{4}+C
$$

but the answer should be:

$$
\frac{3 \sin x^2}{2}+C
$$

Am I doing anything wrong or is it possible to rewrite the solution in another way so that they are the same?

EDIT

Here is my calculation:

$$3\int x\cos^2x = 3\int x\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos2x)dx=\frac{3}{2}\int x+x\cos2x dx=\frac{3x^2}{4}\int x\cos2x dx=\frac{\sin2x}{2}-\int \frac{\sin2x}{2}dx=\frac{\sin2x}{2}x+\frac{\cos2x}{24}$$

But as said, the assumption $\cos^2x=\cos x^2$ is clearly wrong.

Comment: Your version is not equivalent to the correct answer.

Comment: To get the answer you are heading for, it would seem that the integral should be written as $$\int3x\cos\left(x^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Show us the steps you used to get to your answer? Because then we can help identify some of the errors in your way :)

Comment: @robjohn I know many math teachers and professors who *hate* the common shorthand of omitting the brackets/parentheses from trig functions for exactly this reason.

Comment: Updated with steps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Let $t=x^2$, $dt=2x\,dx$ and the rest should be simple.

So: yes, there is a mistake in your solution. Your answer cannot be identical with the correct one, because the former function is periodic and the latter not.

Comment: This looks like a perfectly good hint. Why the downvote?

Comment: I suspect that I misunderstood the $cosx^2$ i interpreted it as cos^2x...

Comment: @theva even accounting for that you don't get the result you show..we can help if you show us then we can fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

U-Substitution
first

$$ u = x^2 $$
Therefore $$du = 2xdx $$
then $$  \frac{du}{2x} = dx$$

$$ \int 3x \cos x^2 \, dx =\int 3x \cos x^2 \frac{du}{2x} = \int \frac{3}{2} \cos u \, du =  \frac{3}{2}\int \cos u\, du $$

Now you can figure integral of cos out by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int 3x \cos(x^2) \, dx = \frac{3}{2} \sin(x^2) + C 
$$

as can be checked by

$$
\left[\frac{3}{2} \sin(x^2) + C \right]' = \frac{3}{2} \, \cos(x^2)\,  2x = 3x \cos(x^2)
$$

If you do not see it, you could use the substitution $u = x^2$:
$$
\int 3x \cos(x^2) \, dx = \int 3x \cos(u) \, \frac{du}{2x} = \int \frac{3}{2} \cos(u) \, du= \frac{3}{2} \sin(u) + C = \frac{3}{2} \sin(x^2) + C 
$$